# Fast bit compression and arithmetic

Tags: c++, algorithm, compression, bit-manipulation, bitmask

I'm working on a C++ library to manage very large value masks (each 2^32 bits, about .5 GB). Each value mask will represent possible values of an 32-bit int. For example, `00101000` would represent the values 2 and 4. Each value mask will contain mostly repetitive data (example: `01010000010100000101000001010000`).

I'm looking for some kind of compression algorithm that allows somewhat-easy bitwise operations on the values of two value masks. Clarification: I don't want to do bitwise operations on the value mask itself, but the values. See example below:

```
ValMask mask_a(0b00101000); // Represents 2 and 4
ValMask mask_b(0b10110000); // Represents 0, 2 and 3

// Sum all of the values of mask_a and mask_b
ValMask mask_c = mask_a + mask_b;
// mask_c is 0b00101111, which represents 2, 4, 5, 6, 7
```

My class will include these operators: +, -, &, |, ^, ~, <<, and >>

Obviously, it would be really nice if I could calculate the result of some of these operators without decompressing the value mask. I doubt any compression algorithm can do all of those (challenge, anyone?), but is there are any existing libraries or algorithms for something like this?

Comment: Any data structure that supports the addition operator on these bit-masks must necessarily support that operation in at least O(n) time, n = 2^32;  Otherwise, you could solve the Subset-sum problem in polynomial time with it.  I'm sure a similar result can be shown for -, and possibly &, |, and ^ as well.  So it's looking pretty grim as far as compression ops goes - what patterns of repetition do you have to work with?

Comment: @torquestomp A typical value mask could probably be best represented as the xor of a set of ranges that include a min, max, and step. For example, the repetitive data example in my question would be represented as (min: 1, max: 2^32, step: 8) xor (min: 3, max: 2^32, step: 8). Now that I think about it, that could actually be a very good compressed format.

Comment: You could use a ZDD with 32 variables to represent any set of 32-bit ints. Many of those sets would take significantly less than 0.5GB, but some will take more. OR, AND and XOR would correspond to JOIN, MEET and DELTA respectively (the family algebra things, not just union and intersect, they would correspond to or-ing or and-ing the *mask* instead of the values). Shifts by constants correspond to renaming variables and dropping the ones that go out of range. You can build addition and subtraction by composing those things.

Comment: Maybe, you can check BitMagic library? See http://bmagic.sourceforge.net/